# Making vector of Buttons using FlTK with c++

Tags: c++

I am supposed to make the game called 15 sliding puzzle where you click a button, the callback function moves it. Right I am trying to make the board by making a vector or array of but I am confused on how I Would do that. **I don't know how to make a vector of Buttons** and attach them to the window. he attach() is for attaching a single element so I don't know how I would use it with a vecto

> Here is my header file

```
#ifndef LevelOne_h
#define LevelOne_h

#include "GUI.h"
#include "Graph.h"
#include <FL/Fl_JPEG_Image.H>
#include<vector>

using namespace Graph_lib;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Level_One : Graph_lib::Window {
public:
    Level_One(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& title);

private:
    vector<Button> Trial_button;
    static void cb_trial(Address, Address);
    void trial();
};

#endif /* LevelOne_h */
```

> And here is my .cpp file

```
#include "LevelOne.h"

Level_One::Level_One(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& title)
    :Window{xy,w,h,title} ,
     Trial_button{Point{150,150},100,100,"TRIAL",cb_trial}

{
    attach(Trial_button);
}

void Level_One::cb_trial(Address,Address pw)
{
    reference_to<Level_One>(pw).trial();

}

void Level_One::trial()
{
    hide();
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main ()
try{
    Level_One win {Point{100,100},500,500,"The Sliding Tiles Puzzle"};
    return gui_main();
}
catch (exception& e){ //catches range errors and run_time_errors
    cerr << "error: "<< e.what() <<'\n';
    return 1;
    }
    catch (...){ //catch any exception
        cerr <<"Exception: something went wrong \n";
        return 2;
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Please make clear where you are stuck.

Comment: I don't know how to make a vector of Buttons and attach them to the window. The attach() is for attaching a single element so I don't know how I would use it with a vector